# Import Data in MySQL through CSV file in joined tables simultaneously in both the tables

Tags: mysql, join, import, import-from-excel

I want to import data in 2 joined tables in MySQL database.

**Table1 - students**

1. id (primary key) (INT)
2. name (VARCHAR)
3. gender_id (foreign key) (INT)

**Table2 - gender**

1. gender_id (primary key) (INT)
2. gender (VARCHAR)

**I want to import csv which contains:**

```html
id,name,gender
1,Sheetal,female
2,Reshma,female
3,Kamal,male
4,Roma,female
5,Raman,male
```

Query which I tried is:

```html
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\students.csv'
INTO TABLE students
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

INSERT INTO students(students.id, students.name, gender.gender) 
SELECT FROM students 
LEFT JOIN gender 
ON(students.gender_id=gender.gender_id);
```

Comment: can you share what your code output is? what are you expecting and what are you seeing as a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exchange the data from the csv file and replace it, with the gender_id   from the table gender

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\students.csv'
INTO TABLE students
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE  1 LINES
(id,name ,@gender)
SET gender_id  = (SELECT gender_id  FROM gender WHERE gender  = @gender)
```

But your first line didn't work for me

i replaced it with

```
LOAD DATA  INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/students.csv'
```